# How to get the difference between two GAME TIME?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I know we can use TimeSpan or the subtract() method to get the difference between two times, but my problem is that my game time is different from actual DateTime. So I want the sun to come out every day at 6AM, so I would be looking at the difference between GameTimeManager.Time and 6AM. If the difference is small enough, then trigger the sun to come out. I have no idea how to input the 6AM game time. Below is how I get game time from actual DateTime:

```
public class GameTimeManager : MonoBehaviour{


    private static GameTimeManager Instance;
    //60 sec in game= 1 sec in REAL LIFE
    public const int TimeScale = 60;
    public const int UpdateRealSec = 1;

    [SerializeField]
    private float TimeSpeed = 1;

    public static DateTime Time{ private set; get; } //prperty of class/struct DateTime
    
    public static void AddTime(double hour){
        Time = Time.AddHours(hour);
        foreach(var dic in TimeRegDic){
            dic.Key.Invoke();
        }
    }
    
    public void Set(){
        
    }
    
    private void Awake(){
        Instance = this;
        Time = new DateTime(1,1,1,7,00,0); //first year, month, day, 7AM 0 seconds
    }
    

    void Start(){
        RegisterTimeAciton(GetGameSec(1),OneMinuteGameTimePassed); //every seconds pass, trigger a specific action: add 1 minute to clock
        //Debug.Log(Time);
    }

    public static float GetGameSec(float sec){
        return sec * TimeScale; //1*60 
    }

    public static float GetRealSecFromGameSec(float gameSec){
        return gameSec / TimeScale;
    }
    
    /*public static float GetGameHourFromRealSec(float sec)
    {
        return 
    }*/
    void OneMinuteGameTimePassed(){
        //Debug.Log(DateTime.Now);
        Time = Time.AddMinutes(1);
        
    }

    void OnWork(WorkData data, double workHour)
    {
        Time = Time.AddHours(workHour);
    }

    private static Dictionary<Action, Coroutine> TimeRegDic = new Dictionary<Action, Coroutine>();
    public static void RegisterTimeAciton(float spaceGameSec, Action onDo){
        TimeRegDic.Add(onDo, Instance.StartCoroutine(ItemEventCounter(spaceGameSec, onDo)));
    }

    



    public static void UnRegisterTimeAciton(Action onDo){
        if(!TimeRegDic.ContainsKey(onDo)) return;
        Instance.StopCoroutine(TimeRegDic[onDo]);
        TimeRegDic.Remove(onDo);
    }

    static IEnumerator ItemEventCounter(float spaceGameSec, Action onDo){
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(GetRealSecFromGameSec(spaceGameSec));
        onDo.Invoke();
        yield return ItemEventCounter(spaceGameSec,onDo);
    }
}
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with [tag:unityscript]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private DateTime Begin;
public const int TimeScale = 60;
public const int UpdateRealSec = 1;

private void Awake()
{
    Begin = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 7, 00, 0);
}

public DateTime GetGameTime()
{
    long gameTickDiff = (DateTime.Now - Begin).Ticks / TimeScale;
    return new DateTime(Begin.Ticks + gameTickDiff);
}
```

call action by update()

```
Update()
{
    var time = GetGameTime();
    bool overAnHour; // check time over one hour , call action
    if(overAnHour)
    {
       foreach(var dic in TimeRegDic)
       {
          dic.Key.Invoke();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the help! Could you explain what this script does? so GetGameTime returns a value of game time based on DateTime. What about my method of getting GameTime using action and coroutine?

Comment: You don't need add time by you self , just call GetGameTime() , it will return right game time. keep simple. and if you want to use action , just run a update() , and check the gametime , if over one hour , just call action.

Comment: Thanks! I finally figured out how to trigger action. But my problem now is that my time is in AM PM so the sun will also come out at 7PM I suppose. How could I avoid this?         ```if (GameTimeManager.Time.Hour == 7)
        {
           if( GetDifference(GameTimeManager.Time, sunOutTime)== 7) //at 7:07AM sun comes out
            {
                GetComponent<Light>().intensity = 2f;
                Debug.Log("Sun comes out");
                
                RenderSettings.skybox = morningSkybox;


            }
        }```

Comment: PM 7 <-- this hour is 19 ? 12+7=19